# excel vba - copy file from one folder to another?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to copy my file from one folder to another folder when a user clicks on a cell in excel.

I keep getting an error saying file not found error, and I don't know why.

my folder names have spaces in so I don't know if this might be the cause of the problem, I have tried removing the spaces in the folder path but same error occurs. can someone please show me what to do thanks in advance

```
     If Target.Column = Range("C1").Column Then
  If Target.Row > 9 Then
    'Declare Variables
 Dim FSO
 Dim sFile As String
 Dim sSFolder As String
 Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
 sFile = "Supplier Audit.xls"

'Change to match the source folder path
 sSFolder = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\"

'Change to match the destination folder path
 sDFolder = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\AX ATTACHMENTS\TEST\"

'Create Object
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
 If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
 MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
 ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
 FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
 MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
 Else
 MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"


  End If
  End If
  End If
```

Comment: I haven't accepted an answer as none of the answers were the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
FSO.CopyFile ("""" & sSFolder & sFile & """"), """" & sDFolder & """", True
```

surrounding the file/folder name with quotes

Comment: hey thanks but no this doesn't work :( still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

1. The path added should be of absolute path
2. Change the line as : Dim FSO as Object